# Is there a way to associate/group a set of file being changed in TFS/VS regardless of change set

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm very new to using TFS/VS2017.   I'm looking to see if there is what I would consider a basic feature of creating a "project" or some other transient Grouping to associate a set of files you are changing.
For example.  Let's say I am working on making 2 changes which are going to be deployed to production on different release dates, but I am working on the changes now.

Let's call these P1 and P2 (Project 1 and Project 2) that I am working on.

P1 I am changing these files:

```
/app1/code/ed.c

/app2/code/bob.c
```

P2 I am changing:

```
/app1/code/ted.c

/app3/code/bill.c
```

Now each time I change these files and check in I get change sets made etc.  But those changes set are just related to whatever I checked in at that moment in time.
They do not reflect "this is the set of files which are related to a single project."
Is there anyway concept of a "project" were I could create a P1 and indicate that P1 contains ed.c & bob.c.  Then do things such as build P1 and it would build both app1 and app2.  Be able to merge/deploy P1 etc.
Right now it seems like I have to keep track of every file in each project on my own. And then build, promote, merge, deploy the apps and files individually.

To try and clarify/assist with what I am asking.  Let's say we use a simpler tool such as Ultra_edit.
In UE, I can create a project and add files to that project.
I can then open a project and it shows me a list of all the related files (so I don't have to go hunting through directory trees to find them over an over).
It does not move the files to a new folder or anything like that.  It just tracks where those files are and gives me a nice clean view of the files relevant to my change.  And it is only the files which are being changed - it's not the whole application - which seem to be how solutions work in VS/TFS.

Thanks for any help.
-ed

Answer (score 0):

Look into using Solutions. If you make each app a project, then you would use two solutions.

In solution 1, you would add in project 1 and 2.
In solution 2, you would add in project 1 and 3.

In each solution, you have the ability to set build dependencies. For example, in solution 1, project 2 relies on project 1. So, when building solution 1, VS will build project 1 before building project 2.

I haven't used visual studio to create a C project, but in a C# project, it will add a cproj file that holds references to all the files in the project. So if you edit the project in one solution, the other solution will reflect the edit.

As for the source control, are you using TFVC or git?

Comment: thanks.  We are using TFS which I assume is the same as TFVC.

Comment: TFS (Team Foundation Server) is the server that the repositories are stored. TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control) is the version control used by the repository. Microsoft TFS supports both TFVC and git. Digging into the terms you used. Change sets is something associated with TFVC. So you are probably correct with TFVC being your version control system.

Comment: i'm 99% sure it's TFVC.  Thank you for the advice